# Javascript functions this.*

Tags: javascript

**Question:** Use Object oriented design to design a class called PhoneBill that calculates and prints the balance owed by each customer of a phone company during the billing period. Your PhoneBill class is to receive the customers current balance and the total time, in minutes, of phone calls during the billing period. the input time is top be validated and the cost of calls is to be calculated at 25c per minute. your class is to print the input balance, the phone call time, the cost of the phone calls and the total amount due

a) Design the class table

b) Write an algorithm for each operation

c) write a test or driver algorithm to test the solution

**code:**

```
 function PhoneBill()
 {
     this.bal;
     this.min;
     this.currCharge;
     this.Totaldue;
     this.currCharges=function()
     {
         this.currCharge=this.min*.25;
     }
     this.Totaldue=function()
     {
         this.Totaldue=this.bal+this.currCharge;
         return (this.Totaldue);
     }
     this.bal=function()
     {
         return (this.bal);
     }
     this.min=function()
     {
         return (this.min);
     }
 }

me= new PhoneBill();
me.balance = eval(prompt("Enter Current Balance: "));
me.minutes = eval(prompt("Enter Minutes Used: "));

document.write("Current Balance = $"+me.balance()+"<p>");
document.write("Minutes Used = "+me.minutes()+"<p>");
document.write("Current Charges = $"+me.currcharges()+"<p>");
document.write("New Balance = $"+me.totaldue()+"<p>");
```

okay so, this is the code i have. I know most of its right because of my professor but there is something wrong. I get an error at line 39 which is:

> `document.write("Current Balance = $"+me.balance()+"<p>");`

I believe it is something above that, which i messed up but i can't figure it out. Help needed please and thank you (:

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I'll give you a hint: Do you know the difference between `foo` and `foo()`?

Comment: 1) If you have an error message, post it. If you don't we're just guessing. 2) Don't use `eval()` - it's bad practice because it's a security hole, and your code doesn't require it.

Comment: @CristiMihai I know what the problem is, I'm just trying to teach the kid somethin' like Mike W says :)

Comment: @Lasse I completely agree, though I assumed he read the error ("I get an error at line 39").

Comment: @CristiMihai OH. In that case: never mind! I just misread your comment then. Cheers.

Comment: Hey sorry, the error i get now is object doesn't support property or method 'currcharges' which is coming from `document.write("Current Charges = $"+me.currcharges()+"<p>");`

Comment: nvm! got it xD just simple mistakes, thanks :b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`me.balance()` is the issue. You are attempting to invoke it as a function, but `me.balance` isn't a function, it is the value of `eval(prompt("Enter Current Balance: "));`

Just use `me.balance` and it should work.

Comment: Yeah i got it to work further now. That prints correctly, but now The error moves down to `me.currcharges()` i tried taking the `()` away, but then it just becomes undefined . xb

Comment: me.currCharges() be wary of the case of your functions also totaldue will throw and error unless it's Totaldue() @user3058571

Comment: @JayLane doh xb , its always the simple mistakes! thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

balance is not a function is what I am seeing in my console.

Did you try:

```
document.write("Current Balance = $"+me.bal+"<p>");
```